# How would "levei uma pica no cu e está doendo até agora" be understood in Portugal?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, português-europeu

In ptBR the message is crystal clear, everybody understands it for what it is: "pratiquei sexo anal receptivo e estou sentindo dor".  In ptPT the meaning can be different. Would a Portuguese listener, at any time, find ambiguity in that sentence? Or is there only one meaning?

Em ptBR a mensagem é clara, e não resta dúvida do que se trata. Minha pergunta é, em ptPT a frase acima pode significar algo completamente diferente do que significa em ptBR? Se alguém disser essa frase em Portugal, poderia haver duplo sentido?

Comment: @Centaurus depende do contexto, tens aqui um exemplo disso: [Quim Barreiros - Picada de Enfermeiro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yw6r3b0clA)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## English

There is only one meaning, in Portugal, and it's crystal clear:

> Levei uma injeção no rabo, e ficou-me a doer até agora.

We would find no ambiguity.

It is worth noting that while, in Portugal, "cu" can mean the anal orifice, its usual meaning is *ass*. This removes much of the sexual connotation.
"Pica" is a child's way to say vaccine.
These two differences, together, would make the sentence similar to:

> I got a vaccine in the [arm/ass/etc], and it's still hurting.

Innocuous, as much as double-entendres allow.

---

## Portuguese

Essa frase tem um único significado, em Portugal, que é claro como água:

> Levei uma injeção no rabo, e ficou-me a doer até agora.

Não haveria ambiguidade ou duplos-sentidos.

Note-se que enquanto, em Portugal, «cu» pode significar o orifício anal, o seu significado normal é o rabo, o traseiro, as nádegas.
«Pica» é a palavra que as crianças usam para dizer «vacina».
Estas duas diferenças, em conjunto, tornam a frase semelhante a:

> Levei uma vacina no [braço/rabo/etc] e ainda me dói.

Inócua — tanto quanto os segundos-sentidos permitam.

Comment: Nota para melhoria: em Portugal, usar "a pica" é como usar (salvo seja) "o papá", ou "o pilau", ou... - linguagem de crianças; e "está doendo" é claramente pt-BR; um portuga podia aperceber-se dessa construção estranha da frase e, especialmente se por algum acaso conhecesse o significado de "pica" no Brasil, perceber o significado alternativo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference between ptPT from ptBR in

> levei uma pica no cu e está doendo até agora

Aside from being gramatically incorrect, which should be:

> Levei uma pica no cu e ainda me dói
>
> /e ainda me está a doer
>
> / e ainda dói
>
> / e ainda está a doer

in ptPT pica also has a secondary meaning. It's slang for penis. Pica is usually a word used by children for 'injection', and rarely used out of that context, unless refering to a penis.

Saying that in Portugal will definetly not be acceptable in most cases, and it's similar (read: exactly) to claiming to have been sodomized.

Comment: `(...) secondary meaning. It's slang for penis.` To make the answer clearer, you should mention the principal meaning before talking about a secondary meaning.

Comment: Which I would've done if it wasn't already well established in the original question